# Optimizing my code for Mathematica Online

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, mathematica-online

I defined this function:

```
s[n_] := Block[{m = 1}, While[Mod[++m!, n] != 0]; m]
```

I would use `ParallelTable` on my laptop, but it would still be quite slow. Tried the online (trial) version, but it is obviously has a bug for it .

[image]

Comment: Exactly what is your question? Are you asking if us to confirm you have encountered a bug? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: It's not unheard of for you to see a dramatic speedup with larger numbers, there oftentimes is a cutoff where a function will use one method which may be faster for smaller iterations, but another that is generally faster for larger iterations. While generally the cutoff will make the code more efficient there are sometimes where it works a little counterintuitively, and possibly could be considered a bug, like in this case...

Comment: What is your interest in Wilson's theorem?